# Fourier Transform of a radial function in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

> Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be radial, i.e. there exists $g: [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = g(|x|)$. Prove that $f$ is also radial. (Note that this result is true for $\mathbb{R}^n$ for a general $n \geq 1$. Here, for $n=2$, you can use the polar coordinates and change of variables.)

So if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is radial, I want to show that there exist a function $h: [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $\hat{f}(\xi) = h(|\xi|)$. I know that:

$$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x)e^{-2\pi i \xi \cdot x} dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} g(|x|)e^{-2\pi i \xi \cdot x} dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(|x|)e^{-2\pi i (\xi_1x_1+\xi_2x_2)} dx_1dx_2$$

I'm not really sure how to procceed from here

Comment: if $r g(r) \in L^1([0,\infty[)$ : $\int_0^\infty 2 \pi r g(r) e^{-2 i \pi |\xi| r} dr$

Comment: @T.Bongers I saw that thread but they have a different definition of radial functions than what I have

Comment: Chappers's answer writes it in exactly the form that you do.....

Comment: Different definition of radial? Almost certainly not.. But that condition is easily seen to be equivalent to the definition, and it's also the crux of the matter.

Comment: @T.Bongers Except I don't understand his answer -- I don't know why the first line is true. Then I don't know how the $f(r)$ disappears and how $sin^{n-2}$ appears. I can certainly copy down the answer, but that does absolutely nothing to further my understanding

Comment: @zhw. I'm sure they are equivalent (otherwise that would be a big issue), but it's certainly not "easily seen" to me at least

Comment: @Brenton That's using polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is exactly the hint given in your statement of the problem.